# Rigid Body objects exploding without colision

Tags: rigidbody

I'm curently working on exploding part of a statue with fracture and rigid body objects. The shot I'm on is a close shot of the shoulder of the statue and I'm trying to explode some kind of "outer layer" of the statue to reveal something else underneath.

The outer layer has been shattered with the fracture add-on. I've managed to stabilise the rigid bodys (so everything doesn't explode right away) by adjusting the collisions shapes (some are on "Convex Hull", some are on "mesh" with a very low margin).
I have then added an icosphere (passive rigid body, animated) to explode the fractured part.

The problem is that some parts explode away at frame 1 without even being touched by the icosphere.

File can be downloaded here (blender 3.0) : https://we.tl/t-v49oAJVDcU

Here are a few screenshots :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0):

Apply the scale of your projectile and it will work:

[image]

Comment: Damn, I was sure I had done that already... So much shame I feel... Thanks a lot anyway !